# An inequality for positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

*If $A$ and $B$ are poitive definite matrices, then*

$n({\rm det} A. {\rm det} B)^{1/n} ≤ {\rm tr}AB$

**I was wondering what are the sufficient and necessary conditions for the equality to hold ?**

Comment: It is always true and I am wondering if it is homework

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* Positive definite matrices always admit (unique) positive definite matrix square roots. Also, for square matrices, the trace of $XY$ is equal to the trace of $YX$. It follows that the inequality in question can be rewritten as
$$
\sqrt[n]{\det(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})}\le\frac{\operatorname{tr}(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})}n.
$$
If you express both sides in terms of the eigenvalues of $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$, the answer will become clear.